# notepad++ pythonscript mark words

Tags: python, macros, notepad++

I am trying to build a pythonscript macro for notepad++ which automates a highlighting feature of the search dialog for several words.

Unfortunately I could not find the necessary function for "highlighting". The script should do the same as if I use the **Ctrl+F dialog, check "Wrap around" and press "Mark All"**.

This one is similar, alghough it does not use a pythonscript:
[notepad++ mark style with macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695157/notepad-mark-style-with-macro)

With the available documentation I could do the following:

```
# Function for marking a line if a certain pattern was found
def bookmarks(lineText, lineNumber, totalLines):    
    patterns = ['word1','word2'] 
    for p in patterns:
        if lineText.find(p) > -1:
            editor.markerAdd(lineNumber, 24) 
    return 1

# mark interesting lines:
editor.markerDeleteAll(24);
editor.forEachLine(bookmarks);
```

This will create bookmarks for all lines containing "word1" or "word2" in the current file. However I would like to highlight the ocurrances as with "Mark All" and I would like to do it **in all opened files**.

Maybe I am missing a documentation resource or it is because I don't know python well. At least I could not find a suitable function to highlight matches. I did use google and I consulted the following documentation pages. 
Also any hint on more valuable documentation is apreciated!

http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/index.html
http://sourceforge.net/p/npppythonscript/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 0):

http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/scintilla.html?highlight=mark#Editor.markerEnableHighlight

Reading docs, i think this can help you:

```
Editor.markerEnableHighlight(enabled)
```

or this one:

```
Editor.markerAdd(line, markerNumber)
```

Later i will try

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. Marker.Add I have already used in my example, it will create a bookmark as intended, but not mark the word (i.e. highlight the word). I tried to add Editor.markerEnableHighlight(True). But there was no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a old topic, but for people that still use "pythonscript macros" in Notepad++, I found a way to mimic the behaviour of search and replace Mark-All.

You need to use scintillia indicators to highlight words of interest. See the [reference](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#Indicators) to learn about scintillia indicators.

You first need to chose a indicator number (~32 available). Be advised that indicators are shared with NPP and linters across defined ranges that i dont know about, so i found myself using the 20th because it just worked. Avoid 1-9 range and the 19th and 29th.

Then you can use the documentation to setup the style of your indicator. Finaly apply the indicator using wraped method `editor.indicatorFillRange(start, lengthFill)`.

Here a script that highlight regex matches using python re module.

```py
from Npp import editor, notepad
import re

patern = notepad.prompt('Please insert a valid python regex', 'regex highlighter', '')

# Highlight matches
for match in re.finditer(patern, editor.getText()):
    editor.indicSetStyle(20, 8)
    editor.indicSetFore(20, (192, 0, 0))
    editor.indicSetAlpha(20, 50)

    editor.setIndicatorCurrent(20)
    editor.indicatorFillRange(match.start(), match.end() - match.start())

# clear the mess
#    editor.setIndicatorCurrent(20)
#    editor.indicatorClearRange(0, editor.getLength())
```

side note: documentation of NPP Python Script is available in your local files `Notepad++/plugins/PythonScript/doc/scintilla.html`.